# mat-tab-group - setting initial tab funcky

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have 3 tabs in a group.
When the dialog loads, I want to select the 3rd tab if there is data passed to the dialog, ie:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.data != null && this.data.imageFileID) {
        this.selectedTabIndex = 2;
      }
    });
  }
```

selectedTabIndex is bound to the tab group:

```
<mat-tab-group #tabs [(selectedIndex)]="selectedTabIndex" ...
```

So, the problem is, when the dialog loads, the 3rd tab is selected but the content of the tab flashes and dissappears.  Manually selecting the 2nd tab does the same, but the first tab is ok.

I dont have any logic in the tabs to hide the entire content.

Like I said... it's funcky!

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-wryjmh) to showcase the issue and the solution: when using the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook in this way, you're causing an 'expression changed after checked' error, but the reason why this isn't showing up in the console is because the `setTimeout` call is essentially making the change outside of Angular's view and not causing the error to surface. Moving the `selectedIndex` logic into the OnInit lifecycle hook (and removing the call to `setTimeout`) fixes your issue.

Comment: Thats awesome, thank you.  The Angular event lifecycle reminds me of ASP.Net web forms...  :/